# CSV to key=>value array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a simple CSV in the form:

```
Joe,2
Peter,321
Jane,34
```

I need to convert this to a key=>value array as follows:

```
$result = array(Joe=>2,Peter=>321,Jane=>34)
```

I can read the CSV file but am unsure how to loop through each line of the CSV to assign the keys and values.

Many thanks.

Comment: It's amusing that the thread is closed as too broad yet someone answered it perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a cheap one-liner to do it:

```
$result = array_column(array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv')), 1, 0);
```

---

It makes use of:

- [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to read the file into an array, giving (newlines omitted for brevity, they disappear in the next step anyway):

  `["Joe,2", "Peter,321", "Jane,34"]`
- [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) to apply [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/str_getcsv) to each element of that array, parsing the comma separated values, giving:

  `[['Joe', '2',], ['Peter', '321',], ['Jane', '34',]]`
- [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) to take that array, grab each element at index 1 from the sub-arrays to use as values, and those at index 0 to use as keys, giving the final result:

```
[
    'Joe' => '2',
    'Peter' => '321',
    'Jane' => '34',
]
```

Comment: Many thanks, Paul...and a much cleaner method than many of the solutions posted on other similar questions.